# ClickListener AND LongClickListener on ListFragment

Tags: android

I have a ListFragment where I would like to add a normal click listener and a long one.

I override the onListItemClick() method on the ListFragment. Here, there is no problem it works.

Then I created an Adapter where I added an OnLongClickListener through setOnLongClickListener() in the getView() method:

```
public class QuestionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private QuestionsBean questions = null;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public QuestionsAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (questions != null && questions.getQuestionList() != null) ? questions.getQuestionList().size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return (questions != null && questions.getQuestionList() != null) ? questions.getQuestionList().get(position) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        QuestionBean question = ((QuestionsBean) questions).getQuestionList().get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_fragment_question, null);

            holder.questionItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemFragmentQuestions);
            holder.questionItem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    System.out.println("test => it works");
                    ;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.questionItem.setText(question.getQuestion());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView questionItem;
    }

    public void setQuestions(QuestionsBean questions) {
        List<QuestionBean> temp = new ArrayList<QuestionBean>();
        if (questions != null && questions.getQuestionList() != null) {
            for (QuestionBean question : questions.getQuestionList()) {
                if (question.isActivated()) {
                    temp.add(question);
                }
            }
            questions.setQuestionList(temp);
        }

        this.questions = questions;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Now, the longClickListener works but not the normal click anymore (actually it works like one time out of 10, or 15 or 20 (it depends...).

I have no idea why when I set both listener, the onListItemClick() doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Thanks for you help.

EDIT: My row xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemFragmentQuestions"
        style="@style/ItemFragmentQuestion"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/itemFragmentQuestionsMarging"
        android:background="@drawable/background_validated" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

My ListFragment class:

```
public class QuestionsFragment extends ListFragment {

    public static final int VALIDATED = 1;
    public static final int IN_PROGRESS = 1;
    public static final int NON_OBSERVED = 1;

    private QuestionsAdapter adapter;
    private QuestionsBean questions;

    public QuestionsFragment() {

    }

    public QuestionsFragment(QuestionsBean questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    public int getShownIndex() {
        return getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("index", 0) : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.adapter = new QuestionsAdapter(inflater);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        View questionsView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_questions, null);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return questionsView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if (l == this.getListView()) {
            QuestionBean question = (QuestionBean) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemFragmentQuestions);
            switch (question.getValue()) {
            case QuestionBean.OK:
                question.setValue(QuestionBean.NOK);
                textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_in_progress);
                break;
            case QuestionBean.NOK:
                question.setValue(QuestionBean.NA);
                textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_non_observed);
                break;
            case QuestionBean.NA:
                question.setValue(QuestionBean.OK);
                textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_validated);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        refresh(this.questions);
    }

    public void refresh(QuestionsBean questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
        adapter.setQuestions(questions);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Menu Title");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Option 1");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Option 2");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        if (item.getTitle() == "Option 1") {
            // Option 1 code here 
       } else if (item.getTitle() == "Option 2") {
            // Option 2 code here
       }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

@Barak As you can see, I set the Adapter in onCreateView() and when I put registerForContextMenu(getListView()) right after, I get an error. It seems that getListView() isn't set yet.

Comment: Have you tried using AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener on the view rather than OnLongClickListener on each row?

Comment: Can you please provide your row xml?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a context menu for the long click rather than muck about in the adapter?

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

and then:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Menu Title");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Option 1");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Option 2");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    if (item.getTitle().equals("Option 1")) {
        // Option 1 code here 
   } else if (item.getTitle().equals("Option 2")) {
        // Option 2 code here
   }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Where do I place the registerForContextMenu(getListView()) ?

Comment: Right after you set the adapter.

Comment: When I place registerForContextMenu(getListView()); in onResume(), it works but I'm not sure it's the best way...

Comment: You put it in the wrong spot.  :)  It should go right after `setListAdapter(adapter)`.  And you can use `registerForContextMenu(Adapter)` rather than making the program do a lookup.

Comment: Still the same error, even if I put it after the setListAdapter() method :(

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(...);` instead of `listView.setOnLongClickListener(...);`.

Sorry for tearing up healing wounds :-)